# Importxml Google spreadsheet "formula parse error"

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to import a value from XML into Google spreadsheet with:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=waterml,2.0&indent=on&sites=04214231&parameterCd=00060,00065&siteStatus=all", "//*[@id="collapsible25"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]")
```

But I'm receiving:

> Formula parse error

The specific data I am trying to import is `3.97` in the node `<wml2:value>3.97</wml2:value>`.

Answer (score 1):

on the xPath parameter, replace `"` by `'`. This is because `"` are used in Google Sheets formulas as text value delimiters.

Other questions with similar problems:

- [Google Spreadsheet xPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9071367/1595451)
- [Google Sheets IMPORTXML XPath Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46777298/1595451)